# reference to type 'const QVariant' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qpushbutton, qsettings

I am trying to save the following modification : to enable the pushButton_4.

```
void Vessels::SaveSettings()
{
    QSettings setting("My_vessels","My_selected_vessels");
    setting.beginGroup("Vessels");
    setting.setValue("selected",ui->pushButton_4->setEnabled(false));
    setting.endGroup();
}
```

When I run, I get this error: 
vessels.cpp:838:33: error: reference to type 'const QVariant' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void'
qsettings.h:167:55: note: passing argument to parameter 'value' here

All what I wanna know, is how to setvalue for an object from this window. I mean enabling the button is just an example.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but note the extra parentheses around `("My_vessels","My_selected_vessels")`. This expression will evaluate to simply `"My_selected_vessels"` due to the comma operator.

Comment: "I get this error: vessels.cpp:838:33" I can be wrong but code snipped you show does not have 838 lines. Should we use telepathy to guess which line produces the error?

Answer (score 3):

```
setting.setValue("selected",ui->pushButton_4->setEnabled(false));
```

`QWidget::setEnabled` returns void, which you can't convert to a `QVariant` in `QSettings::setValue`. Did you mean `ui->pushButton_4->isEnabled()`?

Comment: I understand what you mean but I want to disable the pushButton_4.
What should I do in this case if I cannot use setEnabled(false) ?

Comment: You can't do that in one call: you first have to disable it and then save that it is disabled.

Comment: `ui->pushButton_4->setEnabled(true/false)` then `setting.setValue("selected", ui->pushButton_4->isEnabled())`

Comment: OK thank you I did itand it works. After closing the window with saving the parameters, I want to re-open this window by clicking on "open" button in the mainwindow, this button has to open that window and load the saved parameters, how can I do that please ? The problem is that the button that saves the modifications and the one which load them are not on the same window.
I need your help please!

Comment: If you have a different problem, you can close this question and open a new one.